# How to grant DBSA equivalent rights to OS user on non-root Informix installation?

Tags: linux, informix, access-rights

For a **non**-root Informix v11.7 installation created by `user1`, `user1` impliclitly is granted DBSA rights.

How to grant `user2` the equivalent rights as `user1`, that are DBSA rights?

`user2` shall be able to

- toggle the DB-server between single user- and online-mode (`onmode -j/-m`)
- run the `dbexport` and `dbimport` tools.

Both user accounts (`user1` and `user2`) are OS user accounts.

---

**Update:**

The `$INFORMIXDIR`-tree is owned by `user1:group1` and `user2` is member of `group1`.

If `user2` runs `onmode/dbexport/dbimport` as mentioned above, the following error message is issued (roughly):

`onmode -j` and `onmode -m` return:

```
Must be a DBSA to run this program
```

`dbexport "db@dbs" -c -q -ss` and `dbimport -c -q -i . "db@dbs"` return:

```
-1809 - Server rejected the connection.
```

and the log file shows:

```
00:00:00  Reject connection - 12
00:00:00  Error: Local user validation failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember, we concluded that it was not reliable to allow members of the owner's group to be treated as DBSA (or DBSSO or AAO) because, in general, people who can't use a regular root-privileged installation of Informix would also not be able to control who belongs to the group(s) that they belong to.  Thus, a private installation of Informix is administered by a single administrator.  We looked long and hard at the alternative, but there wasn't a truly reliable way to fix it.

So, I don't think you can have a DBSA group with a private server.

Answer (score 0):

The DBSA group is determined by the group that owns $INFORMIXDIR/etc.

http://www.iiug.org/forums/ids/index.cgi/read/15472

On a non-root installation the DBSA can delegat any other User with DBSA rights through adding that user to that group

```
ALTER USER bill MODIFY UID 1361, ADD GROUP (dbsa), ADD HOME "/u/user1";
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1824.htm

Comment: That is certainly true of a standard `informix`-owned server (with some `root` privileges on some executables).  I'm not sure it is true of a private server.  Once upon a time (about 18 months ago), I knew the answer pat.  Now I'm going to have to rack my brain to check on it.  My suspicion is that you can't have a DBSA group with private (non-root) servers.

Comment: The argument to `GROUP` refers to OS user groups. We however have no group `dbsa` so the `ALTER` fails, if I replace it with `group1` `ALTER` succeeds. However behabviour when trying to use the tools as per my question does not change.